# Microsoft Entra External ID for customers - Entra ID sign-in flow

Tags: microsoft-entra-id

I'm investigating a scenario where end users are invite-only (so no sign-up), but I'd also need to support multiple identity providers (IdP), lets say: Entra ID and Google.

If I don't define user flow for my application, it works with Entra ID IdP, and only supports signing in with Entra ID. Great!

[image]

As soon as I want to bring in Google as IdP next to Entra ID, I need to create User flow. In this user flow, however, I cannot select "Entra ID". This is mentioned in the documentation, fair enough, as it's no-go in terms of sign-up. So what this means, that user cannot sign in using Entra ID anymore, only using Google IdP or with local email+password.

[image: Email changed for privacy]

I'd want to support sign-in for both Entra ID and Google IdPs. Is there any way to implement this currently in the preview version of "Microsoft Entra External ID for customers"?